# SQL: Can I INSERT some fields from variables other from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

SQL Question

I wonder if I can write a single sql `INSERT` statement to insert a row into a table where some of the fields come from variables and others come from another table.  Currently I select from `tableA`, store the fields in variables and then insert them into `tableB`.
In the following example I'd like to get `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` from `tableA` and the rest from variables. (mysql)

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tableA where product = 5";
```

php code

```
$sql = "INSERT tableB
SET     
fkey = 100,
custid = 10,
product = 5,
field1 = '$field1',
field2 = '$field2',
field3 = '$field3' ";
```

Comment: Please check this SO posting  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table.  I think it answers your question.

Comment: thanks. my question must not be clear. I am trying to get field1 etc from tableA in the same tableB INSERT statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you just mix literal values and fields in a select and insert:

```
insert into tableB (fkey, custid, product, field1, field2, field3)
select 100, 10, 5, field1, field2, field3
from tableA
where product = 5
```

Comment: actually I'm sorry I didn't understand your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tableB (fkey, custid, product, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT 100, 10, product, field1, field2, field3 FROM tableA
 WHERE product = 5
```

You can, of course, replace constants in above statement with your variables.

Comment: thanks yes, of course which I do. I was trying to make the question understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put your variables in quotes for it to work correctly.

```sql
INSERT INTO tableB (fkey, custid, product, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT '$A', '$B', product, field1, field2, field3
  FROM tableA
 WHERE product = 5
```