# How to store a table as two different tables using the AS function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to store table1 using the AS function as t1 and t2. How do I do this?

Comment: You should expand a little on what you want to do. This is very vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create table as well

```
SELECT * INTO table1
FROM t1;
```

If the table is already created

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT* FROM t1;


INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT* FROM t2;
```

[How to do INSERT into a table records extracted from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?529221-RESOLVED-create-table-as-select-in-MS-Access