# How can I copy records from Access Table to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to copy data from an access table into sql server. I have thought about just linking the tables but this will not work for what I am trying to do. I need the data to export from the access table to the sql server when I click a macro button. Are there any ideas on how I can get started or where to look?

Comment: Google?  `Insert Into`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do INSERT into a table records extracted from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table)

Comment: This seems to be internal to access, it is the right idea. I just need it from Access to SQL Server.

Comment: Use Access to Link your SQL tables and insert as if they're Access tables. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/link-to-sql-server-data-HA102809758.aspx

Comment: Just FYI, SO isn't for "getting started" or "discussion" questions, it's to help with very specific problems with your code.  Google is usually a good place to start otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro could use the `RunCode` action to run a VBA function similar to this one:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function TransferTableToSqlServer()
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
            acExport, _
            "ODBC Database", _
            "ODBC;" & _
                "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
                "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                "Database=myDb;" & _
                "Trusted_Connection=Yes;", _
            acTable, _
            "sourceTableName", _
            "destinationTableName", _
            False
End Function
```

For more information see

[DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214131%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: What if I have a username and password I need to enter?

Comment: @user2119980 you can replace the `Trusted_Connection=Yes;` parameter with `UID=xxx;PWD=yyy;`. See connectionstrings.com for details.

Comment: So like this then:                                             Public Function Update()
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
            acExport, _
            "ODBC Database", _
            "ODBC;" & _
                "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
                "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                "Database=DATABASE;" & _
                "Username=USERNAME;" & _
                "Password=PASSWORD;" & _
            acTable, _
            "CDData", _
            "dbo.AC_CDData", _
            False
End Function

Comment: @user2119980 something along those lines, yes.

Comment: I got it working but it keeps prompting me for the login which I thought if I put in the code which I did above it wouldn't ask me for it?

Comment: @user2119980 If you used `Username=` and `Password=` then I don't think that the ODBC driver will recognize those keywords and hence will prompt you for credentials. Try `UID=` and `PWD=` instead.

Comment: @Gordo Thompson - that worked. But now I have an issue of it not overwriting the table that is there. It says the table already exists which I know it does but I just want it to upload and overwrite anyway. SO I need it to delete the table and replace it with the updated one, or just overwrite the table that is there

Answer (score 1):

I would link/attach to the sql server table you intend to copy to, making sure it has a primary key(so that it doesn't become readonly to access), and then create an access 'Append' query to select data and map them to the columns in sql server.

Writing a macro to then run the query you have written should be trivially easy.

This method will generally work, though can be slow at times with lots of data.

Comment: I did utilize this method, but my supervisor said he did not want it done this way.

Comment: You should ask your supervisor why, and what way s/he prefers then.

Answer (score -1):

Check [Upsizing Wizard](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/convert-access-database-to-sql-server) for data, indexes, and defaults.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to address the problem. The upsizing wizard is for moving a database to SQL server, not data to an existing SQL server DB.