# Select data from another table during insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch max(date) from another table while inserting a record in present table here is my query

```
insert into table2 values (null,12,(select max(odate) from table1),0)
```

this code doesn't seem to work please help

Comment: In you code all date value for all the records is going to be same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select` instead of `insert . . . values`:

```
insert into table2 
    select null, 12, max(odate), 0
    from table1;
```

As a note:  you should get in the habit of including the column names in the `insert()` statement.