# Too few parameters in SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert records from one table into another using a sql statement in vba.  I came up with this but everytime I try to run it, it just says that there are too few parameters and it expected 1.  I am not really sure why this is happening as I triple checked my `INSERT` statement for errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
verifSERFF = "INSERT INTO SERFFVerified ([CLIENT ID], [CLIENT NAME], [MARKET SEGMENT], [FORMULARY ID], [FORMULARY NAME], [FORMULARY VERSION],[SERFF EXPORTED],[SERFF EXPORTED DATE],[APPROVED DATE]) " & _
             "SELECT DD.[CLIENT ID], DD.[CLIENT NAME], DD.[MARKET SEGMENT], DD.[FORMULARY ID], DD.[FORMULARY NAME], DD.[FORMULARY VERSION],DD.[SERFF EXPORTED],DD.[SERFF EXPORTED DATE], DD.[APPROVED DATE] " & _
             "FROM " & tableName & " as DD "
```

Comment: eliminate the space between table and fields?  looks like it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table and if you run it  setting a break point on verifserff.. what is the value of the variable perhaps tablename isn't what you think it is..  or set a msgbox after the line showing the value of verifserff and try to run that statement directly in access...

Comment: Check your column names, Acess will give that "parameters" error when you have a typo (=a name that is not recognised as a column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when the Sql Query Fields dont match with table fields Name Or a Field in Sql Query dont exist in Table.