# How to insert records (plus some non records) from another table into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables, and I want to insert data from one into another.

I only want two columns from table A to be inserted into table B (which has more than two columns). I want to add a bunch of `null`s and 1s into the rest of table B.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74204) which helped, but what if I want to, for example:

```
INSERT into B(name, address, foo, bar, blah)
select name, 'B'+address from table A, 1, 1, null
```

> 'B'+address is throwing the error
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'B' to data type int

Comment: `INSERT into B(name, address, foo, bar, blah)
select name, 'B'+convert(varchar,address), 1, 1, null  from table A`

Comment: what is type of field address in table B? If int then you can not insert varchar into it

Comment: `INSERT into B(name, address, foo, bar, blah)
select name, 'B'+address, 1, 1, null FROM A`

Comment: address is actually a 10 digit int. I need it preserved as B concatenated to that 10 digit int. Right now the 10 digit int is being truncated, only four digits are showing.

Comment: Never mind, DimaSUN's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO B (name, address, foo, bar, blah)
 SELECT name, 'B'+ cast(address as varchar(250)), 1, 1, NULL
 FROM table A
```

'or

```
; with CTE 
 as

 (
 SELECT NAME, 'B'+ cast(address as varchar(250)) [address], 1 AS FOO, 1 AS BAR, NULL AS BLAH 
 FROM TABLE A

 )

 INSERT INTO B (NAME,[ADRESS], FOO, BAR, BLAH)
 SELECT NAME, [ADRESS], FOO, BAR, BLAH 
 FROM CTE
```