# How to move records older than 30 days to another table in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called activation. In here I want to move records older than 30 days to another table. How to do this?

```
 SELECT * DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y') 
 FROM 
 tablename 
 WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

I tried this query but it returns me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM activation WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(SYS' at line 1

Comment: you are missing comma (`,`) between `*` and `DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y')`, it should be `SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM .....`

Comment: do i have to pass anything in %m%d%Y ???

Comment: no, that's the format you want date to be appear at last column, take a look a date_format function, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Okay thanks that solved my error but could you guide me how to move those records to another table

Comment: if you already have table created, simply do `insert into newtable select columnnames from oldtable`, as stated in answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like

```
INSERT INTO tablename2 select *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y') from tablename1 WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);

DELETE FROM tablename1 WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: i get this error :1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: i am still getting that error why?

Comment: plz check if  column count in table1 and table 2 are same ?

Comment: @Ben Swinburne Thanx for edit

Answer (score 1):

Example to how implement:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(LongIntColumn2, CurrencyColumn2)
SELECT LongIntColumn1, Avg(CurrencyColumn) as CurrencyColumn1 FROM tablename GROUP BY LongIntColumn1;
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74204/2925795