# How to create a subset of a table using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have understood that I can write the following query to create a subset of a data set and it worked. I want to use the data set from this query to create another table. How do I save this query as a data set in MS Access?

```
SELECT [24 months Trx raw data].*
FROM [24 months Trx raw data]
WHERE [24 months Trx raw data].ID<=10;
```

Comment: The easiest way is to create a view from the select statement. Note that any updates to the view will reflect in the actual data of the source table(s). If you want to create a new table and insert the data from the source table, you can do execute an [`insert...select` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [SQL will create a new table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx), named *MyNewTableName*, containing the data from the above SQL statement:

```
SELECT [24 months Trx raw data].* INTO MyNewTableName
FROM [24 months Trx raw data]
WHERE [24 months Trx raw data].ID<=10;
```

Comment: Consider creating a query object, it could be used just like a table.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query into a [Make Table query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b).

But almost certainly it is better to keep it as a SELECT query, and not duplicate the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is giving me the error- Astericks cannot be used as totals cannot be calculated on all values. Can you please help me get rid of this error?