# trying to insert data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where user inserts data and the user id should be automatically added to the table which he is accessing.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO leadinform (lead_compname,lead_add,lead_city,lead_compno,lead_cp,lead_cpd,lead_cpno,lead_cpemail,prodtype,prodmodel,value,clodate,uid) VALUES ('$leadname','$leadadd','$leadcity','$leadcompno','$leadcpname','$leadcpdesig', '$leadcpno','$leadcpmail','$prodtype', '$model','$value','$clodate') SELECT admin.uid FROM admin where admin.username = '$user_check' ";
```

This is the code I am using but it doesnt seem to work.

where am I wrong ?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table

Comment: hi, i need to add only one column from another table and all the other data are given by the user himself...

Comment: anyway you should make something like `INSERT INTO leadinform (lead_compname,lead_add,lead_city,lead_compno,lead_cp,lead_cpd,lead_cpno,lead_cpemail,prodtype,prodmodel,value,clodate,uid) SELECT '$leadname','$leadadd','$leadcity','$leadcompno','$leadcpname','$leadcpdesig', '$leadcpno','$leadcpmail','$prodtype', '$model','$value','$clodate', admin.uid FROM admin where admin.username = '$user_check' ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO leadinform (lead_compname,lead_add,lead_city,lead_compno,lead_cp,lead_cpd,lead_cpno,lead_cpemail,prodtype,prodmodel,value,clodate,uid) 
    VALUES ('$leadname','$leadadd','$leadcity','$leadcompno','$leadcpname','$leadcpdesig', '$leadcpno','$leadcpmail','$prodtype', '$model','$value','$clodate',(SELECT admin.uid FROM admin where admin.username = '$user_check' limit 1))  ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO leadinform 
(lead_compname,lead_add,lead_city,lead_compno,lead_cp,lead_cpd,lead_cpno,lead_cpemail,prodtype,prodmodel,value,clodate,uid)
SELECT '$leadname','$leadadd','$leadcity','$leadcompno','$leadcpname','$leadcpdesig', '$leadcpno','$leadcpmail','$prodtype', '$model','$value','$clodate', admin.uid
FROM admin
WHERE admin.username = '$user_check'"
```

And please check [insert-select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: hi, only one column ie the user id should be added from another table and all the other info are given by the user thru php

Comment: @Jayashreevenugopal Yes? No? Sorry, I could not get you.

Comment: i have 7 columns in my table,6 columns are entered by user and the 7th column(user id) shud be added dynamically from the other table ,

Comment: @Jayashreevenugopal what's wrong with this answer? Did you actually try it?

Comment: @Jayashreevenugopal - His query does exactly what you want. Try "copy/paste" and test it. When you write `SELECT '$leadname', ...` it means that it will return the value of `$leadname` and not a column from the database.

Comment: sorry,i tested ,it doesnt work.... i dont still get it... the admin table has only 3 columns,i am trying to add only the uid from the admin table to another table

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO leadinform (lead_compname,lead_add,lead_city,lead_compno,lead_cp,lead_cpd,lead_cpno,lead_cpemail,prodtype,prodmodel,value,clodate,uid) 
    VALUES ('$leadname','$leadadd','$leadcity','$leadcompno','$leadcpname','$leadcpdesig', '$leadcpno','$leadcpmail','$prodtype', '$model','$value','$clodate',(SELECT admin.uid FROM admin where admin.username = '$user_check' limit 1))  ";
```

Comment: just 20 minutes late your